# Regression with LSTMs

Tags: tensorflow, time-series, regression, lstm, nan

I'm trying to use LSTMs for regression. The input has the dimension of (m,1280) where m is the number of training examples and I have 1280 numbers for each training example. Take, for example, m=10. The output is a single number between 70 and 150.

```
X_train = np.random.uniform(0, 3.5,(m,1280))
Y_train = np.random.uniform(70, 150,(m,1))
```

Here is my code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=128, activation='relu', return_sequences = True, input_shape=(1280, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(LSTM(128,return_sequences=False,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001))
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32, shuffle=True,verbose=1)
```

Firstly, it takes too long for the model to run each epoch. Secondly, the cost is high at the first epochs and after several epochs it becomes nan.

```
Epoch 1/100
1/1 [==============================] - 6s 6s/step - loss: 12701.2432
Epoch 2/100
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 12689.3740
Epoch 3/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: 12655.2412
Epoch 4/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: 12615.0010
Epoch 5/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: 12569.9473
Epoch 6/100
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 12513.8174
Epoch 7/100
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: 12404.4121
Epoch 8/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 9/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 10/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 11/100
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 12/100
1/1 [==============================] - 3s 3s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 13/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 14/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: nan
Epoch 15/100
1/1 [==============================] - 2s 2s/step - loss: nan
```

I tried 10,32 and 256 for LSTM units. I also tried changing the learning rate, different values in dropout, and deleting the second layer of LSTM. But, it takes so long to run and the cost function is still so high.

Comment: 1200 timesteps? it's normal that it takes a while..

Comment: about the loss.. you have  random data as input and as output... thus the network, the only way it has to improve/decrease the loss, is to overfit (thus, it's very sensible to small changes in the parameters)... you should see that with Adam(1e-6) it improves, but the problem is still there

Comment: Thank you, Alberto, but I changed the interval of random data and it didn't workout. Actually, my final data is this (0,3.5) frame and I decreased the length and generated random data in (2 or 3, 3.5) to make it less random and still the cost is either fluctuating or increasing. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: no, the problem is not the range, but the correlation between your input and output data. How is the net supposed to map from random data to random data??

Comment: As correctly mentioned by @Alberto Sinigaglia, You should try using real data rather than random data. Also you can use `mean_absolute_error` loss function to avoid squaring the loss.